# check if null produces errors - can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter

I wanna check if the `Icon` doesn't return null and if it returns null then show the `SvgPic`  , or else show the `Icon` .

**Errors:**

1. Too many positional arguments,
2. The property 'icon' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

.

```
final SvgPicture? svgPic; final Icon? icon;
child: Container(widget.icon == null
                                ? widget.svgPic
                                : Icon(widget.icon.icon,
                                    color: widget.iconColour)),
                          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Too many positional arguments*

You didn't add any parameter label in that container

- *The property 'icon' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')*

You are trying to access the icon property of a nullable, so you need to use ? or !.

Instead of:

```
Container(widget.icon == null ? widget.svgPic
   : Icon(widget.icon.icon, color: widget.iconColour),
),
```

Use:

```
Container(child: widget.icon == null ? widget.svgPic
   : Icon(widget.icon!.icon, color: widget.iconColour)
),
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation and the solution, it works.